# iOS: Best way to get position user

Tags: ios, dictionary, geolocation

I have a MKMapView class, and I want to show on the map the user position represented by a image.
So, I read this tutorial: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application

This guy use the locationmanager on the view, I need to use it on a MKMapView.

For me, the best way to do this is creating a class just for control the user position?
How can I do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First you want the location to show up on your map:

`yourMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;`

Then you need to handle the delegate method for displaying an annotationview for the user location:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        // Create a custom MKAnnotationView here that will display your image.
    }
}
```

Make sure you set the `delegate` on your `MKMapView` properly.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to implement the `MKAnnotation` & `MKMapView` Delegates.

Implement this method for changing the default pin to the custom image.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
  {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        // Create a custom MKAnnotationView here that will display your image.
        //user current location
    }

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";   
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyLocation class]])
    {

        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil)
        {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        }
        else
        {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];

        return annotationView;
    }

    return nil;    
}
```

Please refer this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial).